# Same configuration but one brings: Error SQLSTATE[23000] column cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are already tons of posts concerning this error and I do know how and why it occured. My problem is, that I am using the same configuration and I am running almost identical codes, but only one page brings the error, after the form has been sent. The corresponding columns in the database have exactly the same configuration: Null is off (so actually both have to respond with an error) and the type is varchar, both on autoincrement. I don't know, if it really helps to post the code fragments here, I just hope someone knows/already had a similar occurence with this error.

Now here is the first code for the insert command and the form, which brings no error after it is sent. I have a dropdown button for selecting a subject2, which can also just be left untouched (I shortened the form):

```
<form name="lfb" action="lfb.php#lfbjump" method="post">

<select name="subject2">
<option value="">choose another subject</option>
<?php foreach ($subjects->fetchAll() as $subject): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $subject['fach_id']; ?>"><?php echo $subject['subject']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

</form>
```

The corresponding insert command (shortened):

```
$order =  "
INSERT INTO $dbname.$tablename (

subject2)

VALUES (

:subject2)";

try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$statement = $pdo->prepare($order);

$statement->bindParam(':subject2', $subject2);


$subject2 = $_POST['subject2'];

$statement->execute();
```

And now the other dropdown, which is loaded via ajax (does this make a difference?) and which brings the error:

```
<select name="noteniveau1">
  <option value="">please choose</option>
  <option value="1">example 1</option>
  <option value="2">example 2</option>
</select>
```

The insert commmand (it is in a loop -> $nr goes from 1 to 4).:

```
$order =  "
INSERT INTO $dbname.$tablename (

noteniveau)

VALUES (

:noteniveau)";


try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$statement = $pdo->prepare($order);


$statement->bindParam(':noteniveau', $noteniveau);

$noteniveau = $_POST["noteniveau$nr"];

$statement->execute();
```

And the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'noteniveau' cannot be null' in /var/www/xx/html/xx/xx.php:199 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/xx/html/xx/xx.php(199): PDOStatement->execute() 
#1 /var/www/xx/html/xx/xx.php(438): include('/var/www/xx...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/xx/html/xx/xx.php on line 199
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$noteniveau1`?

Comment: Make sure your `$nr` variable is actually equal to `1` as I'm assuming that is what you are expecting. Also, I'd try `$_POST['noteniveau'.$nr]` and see if that works. Sometimes the imbedded variables don't work very intuitively.

Comment: Hey, sorry forgot to write that; I have the inserts in a loop, the $nr increments from 1 to 4. Currently I have set the database to null = accepted, but now I have a big fat NULL in the cell where nothing has been inserted while the other database just leaves a space there without the NULL (with null not being "turned on" in the column configuration)

Comment: @kunruh hey thanks, that is (again) the error... even though I thought I would have tested that some days before. However now `$_POST["noteniveau$nr"]` simply doesn't work anymore with the imbedded variable and sadly, `$_POST['noteniveau'.$nr]` also doesn't.. Looks like I got a big new problem yay! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both inserts, you are using a variable before assigning it.  Just because you're not getting an error in the first insert doesn't mean that you actually end up successfully inserting.  You should have:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare($order);
$subject2 = $_POST['subject2'];
$statement->bindParam(':subject2', $subject2);
$statement->execute();
```

And for the second insert:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare($order);
$noteniveau = $_POST["noteniveau$nr"];
$statement->bindParam(':noteniveau', $noteniveau);
$statement->execute();
```

Note that the assignment is moved to before usage.

You should also have a proper error handling for when the submitted data isn't what you're expecting.

Comment: Gthanks for the input, I will revamp my codes, guess it is better as you recommend it even though the other codes following that queue of bindings have not caused any troubles until now. The error from above is indeed caused by the `$_POST["noteniveau$nr"]` - the variable isn't interpreted/imbedded correctly though it worked some days before.. I guess I will do it without a loop now.. :/